# Perform replace on a string but ignore some pattern

Tags: java, regex

I (Regex noob) am trying to perform replace operation on a string containing some pattern. For example

`AAA-BBB-CCC-{AAA-BBB-AAA-BBB}-CCC-BBB-AAA`

In the above I am trying to replace all `A`s with `I`s but **ignore** the `A`s inside curly braces.

For this what I could do is to split the entire string on the pattern and perform replace then concatenate the strings.

I was wondering if there is a shorter way in regex so that I could perform something like

```
String str = "AAA-BBB-CCC-{AAA-BBB-AAA-BBB}-CCC-BBB-AAA";
str = str.replaceButIgnorePattern("A", "I","\\{(.*?)\\}");
System.out.print(str);   //III-BBB-CCC-{AAA-BBB-AAA-BBB}-CCC-BBB-III
```

And the pattern can be like

1. *contains any character*
2. *can be at starting, in between or at the end of the string*

Comment: A common workaround is `str.replaceAll("A(?![^{}]*})", "I")`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

***Considering there are no nested braces***, a solution is to match a substring inside the closest `{` and `}` and match and capture the pattern to replace, and then check if the Group 1 is not null and then act accordingly.

In Java 9+, you may use

```
String text = "AAA-BBB-CCC-{AAA-BBB-AAA-BBB}-CCC-BBB-AAA";
Pattern r = Pattern.compile("\\{[^{}]*}|(A)");
Macher m = r.matcher(text);
String result = m.replaceAll(x -> x.group(1) != null ? "I" : x.group() );
System.out.println( result );
```

See the [online demo](https://ideone.com/QXGqmu).

Here, `\{[^{}]*}` matches `{`, any 0+ chars other than `{` and `}`, and then `}`, or (`|`) captures `A` into Group 1.

Equivalent code for older Java versions:

```
String text = "AAA-BBB-CCC-{AAA-BBB-AAA-BBB}-CCC-BBB-AAA";
Pattern r = Pattern.compile("\\{[^{}]*}|(A)");
Matcher m = r.matcher(text);
StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer();
while (m.find()) {
    if (m.group(1) == null) {
        m.appendReplacement(sb,  m.group(0));
    } else {
        m.appendReplacement(sb,  "I");
    }
}
m.appendTail(sb);
System.out.println(sb);
```

See the [online Java demo](https://ideone.com/F1dfZt).

You may also use a common workaround for any Java version:

```
str = str.replaceAll("A(?![^{}]*})", "I");
```

where `(?![^{}]*})` makes sure there is no any 0+ occurrences of `{` and `}` followed with a `}` immediately to the right of the current location. **NOTE** this approach implies that the string contains a balanced amount of open/close braces.

Comment: Which approach is more preferred in terms of performance, since regular expressions are "heavyweight"?

Comment: @Steyrix These are different approaches, you need to choose one based on the requirements, not performance. They are both good from the performance point of view. Neither handles nested braces though. Let know if you need a solution for nested braces, too.

Comment: Thanks @WiktorStribiżew As I am currently on Java 8 I used the second approach and it worked. Many thanks.

Comment: @qwerty  I added the equivalent code for the first approach working in legacy Java versions.

Comment: Thanks @WiktorStribiżew. Any special cases where you recommend the first approach over the second?

Comment: @qwerty Yes, I have added a note at the bottom. If you do not know whether the braces are paired, use the first approach